# Dot product consuming lot of memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two 2D tensors A and B of size [I,J] and I want to dot product each jth vector of A  with jth vector of B. It is consuming a lot of memory.
I'm doing it like this:

```
for j in range (J):
      K.dot(K.reshape(A[:,j], [1,-1]),K.reshape(B[:,j], [-1,1]))
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum):

```
tf.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, B)
```

Comment: This will multiply all vector of A with all vector of B. I want to multiply  the first of A with the first of B, then the second of A with the second of B, the third of A with the third of B...etc

Comment: @MohamedAmineMahmoudi Right, I changed my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: how can do the following using einsum:                                                                                                                                                                                       for j in range (J):
      (K.dot(K.reshape(A[:,j], [1,-1]),K.reshape(B[:,j], [-1,1]))+c)**p                                                      is this correct (tf.einsum('ij,ij->j', A, B)+c)**p

Comment: @MohamedAmineMahmoudi You can check whether it's correct by running an example. Otherwise you can ask a separate question for that.